# Why are cronjobs running at the wrong time?

Tags: cron, timezone, ubuntu-10.10

I have cronjobs setup to be run daily on my Ubuntu server.

eg. 0 4 * * *  command

They are running except they are running 8 hours early.  When setting up the server, it was originally set to UTC time.  I ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` to set the server to CST which is 6 hours behind UTC.  Interestingly, I am in PST which is 8 hours behind UTC but I don't see how the server could know that.

If I run the command `date`, it shows the time in CST.

There must be some place that the time is configured wrong.  Where can I look to solve this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Did you remember to restart cron after changing your time zone? If not, cron may still have its old notion of the time zone from when it was originally started.

While not strictly necessary I usually suggest rebooting a machine after changing the time zone -- A server's time zone shouldn't ever change (or at least it should be *VERY* infrequent), and this guarantees that every program on the server has been restarted and knows about the change :-)

Comment: No, I didn't restart.  I have done that and will wait to see if that is the problem (which I think it may be).

Comment: After restart cron service, it's now run at the time same with timezone that I have set using tzdata. Thanks.

Comment: I noticed the entries in /var/log/cron were showing the wrong time even after restarting crond. Restarting rsyslog fixed that issue.

Comment: @WildVelociraptor Yeah syslog will also use the old timezone data until restarted (so it's going to timestamp things wrong even though they're running at the right time). Anything else that's long-running and started before the timezone data changed will exhibit similar behavior, which is why a reboot is generally indicated.

Comment: Remember?  Common sense would dictate that cron would read the system time, not keep it's own record of time.  How would we know to "remember" to do that?

Answer (score 8):

For me, I found that when I run the  `hwclock` command the time was an hour different than when I ran the `date` command.  To fix that you can call `hwclock --systohc` which will sync the two times and run the cronjobs at the expected time.

Comment: In my case both `date` and `hwclock` report identical time, but cron still doesn't do what I'd expect it to.

Comment: You safe my life, thanks so much hwclock --systohc fix the wrong date for me =)

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20 restart the cron daemon with:

`sudo service cron restart`

Answer (score 1):

To verify this issue, you can also see the cron logs, you will see the unwanted time in the cron logs.
This problem is faced when the timezone is set but cron service is not restarted. In addition, you should also restart rsyslog service.

Please issue this command to fix this issue.

```
sudo systemctl restart crond
sudo systemctl restart rsyslog
```